# User-defined function with no arguments, in R, in pipe

Tags: r, function, pipe

I would like to write a function that does not have arguments, and that can be referenced in a pipe (%>%), so I don't have to repeat several lines of code. However, I'm not getting it after multiple tries. I would also appreciate help on writing a function referred to in a pipe, with arguments. Many thanks for any help! Simplified example follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(11:20)
c <- data.frame(a, b)
c
#>     a  b
#> 1   1 11
#> 2   2 12
#> 3   3 13
#> 4   4 14
#> 5   5 15
#> 6   6 16
#> 7   7 17
#> 8   8 18
#> 9   9 19
#> 10 10 20
y <- function() {
  filter(d<5)
}

c %>% mutate(d = a*b) %>% y()
#> Error in y(.): unused argument (.)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipe considers the first argument of the function is the data, for example the first arguments of mutate or filter are both the data. So when you do `mtcars %>% mutate(a = 5)` you are actually doing `mutate(mtcars, a = 5)`.

So you would have to modify it to:

```
y <- function(data) {
  filter(data, d < 80)
}

c %>% mutate(d = a*b) %>% y()

  a  b  d
1 1 11 11
2 2 12 24
3 3 13 39
4 4 14 56
5 5 15 75
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. Sorry, my example wasn't clear enough in an effort to be too simple. In my modified example, it doesn't matter whether I reference c or not in the function. The problem is: how do I refer to the data after it has been modified in a series of commands?

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you want, but doing the same way I answered would still work with your example:
`y <- function(data) { filter(data, d < 80) }`


`c %>% mutate(d = a*b) %>% y()`.
  

in this case y() will get the mutated c as first argument.

Comment: Yes, that works the way I need, big thank you! I don't clearly understand the theory behind what was needed but I can use your answer to solve my problem.

Comment: @David you can take a look at: [r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html)

Comment: PS. I would like to vote your modified answer as correct; it will match the modified example. Not sure how to do this unless the answer is modified. Again, thanks.

Comment: @David just modified it, take a look if it's ok for you. I just changed 5 for 80 so the filter doesn't return a data frame with 0 rows.

Comment: Done. Thanks again for your answer.